# Microsoft Smart Client Composite UI

Tags: composite, smartclient

I have been trying to run the project given in this [MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188688.aspx) but am unable to do it. There is reference to Microsoft.IntegratedDesktop.Controls.StackBar namespace in one of the project but I'm not able to find the DLL(IDF.Controls.DLL as it is referenced) that contains this namespace. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft.IntegratedDesktop.Controls.StackBar control can be found in the self-extracting executable here:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/7/f279e71e-efb0-4155-873d-5554a0608523/MSDNMag2006_09.exe

Comment: Thanks I was eventually able to compile the application.